# UITableViewController - count sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in this method -

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I'd like to trigger a method only if there is more than one section - how do i do a section count here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a delegate method numberOfSectionsInTableView, just call :

```
[self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to prevent this method from being called, but what you can do is return `nil` if you don't want a header.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView] > 1){
        //Create your view and return it
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```